Dialog / Bottomsheet Flutter Web not popping when trigger by device back trigger / manual back by keyboard at desktop
Dialog / Bottomsheet Flutter Web not popping when trigger by device back trigger / manual back by keyboard at desktop
it should popping dialog / bottomsheet first before page, but the condition its popping page, and nothing happen with dialog / bottomsheet

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use WillPopScope  widget and you can control the back key action
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () => _backPressed(_yourKey),
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Page(),
    bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavigationBar(navBarOnTapCallback),
  ),
);

_backPressed in this function you can trigger the navigator pop
